# Any way to delete the app once it was opened ？

Tags: applescript, bash

I just created an app (Let's say Test1) with AppleScript. It's used to activate another app (Let's say Test2). What I want to do is to delete Test1 or move Test1 to Trash, once Test2 was launched. AppleScript, Unix shell, Python, Perl or other language is welcome. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Allan Let's put it this way: I would like to install Egnyte Drive, which will require the administrator's name and password the first time it launches. So I create another app with AppleScript to input administrator's name and password automatically, when Egnyte Drive launches. But I would like to delete the app which I created, once Egnyte Drive launches.

Comment: So, you are looking to *deploy* an app which requires admin privileges to install/run?

Comment: @Allan Yes, exactly.